# does the OMPL package work for diamondback?

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, ompl-ros-interface, ompl, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It comes by default with electric, but I can't seem to find it in diamondback version.
Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30155/does-the-ompl-package-work-for-diamondback?/) by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2012-03-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on 2012-03-22**:
It's actually the ompl_ros_interface (the one contained in arm_navigation stack) which I can't find for diamondback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a version of ompl in diamondback. See the [ompl wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/1919/carlos/) on 2012-03-22**:
Thanks! but I understand that ompl_ros_interface in the arm_navigation stack is the one that does the planning task, but if I install arm_navigation for diamondback (sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-arm-navigation), it doesn't come with the ompl_ros_interface package

**Comment by [Tully](https://answers.ros.org/users/7/tully/) on 2012-03-23**:
There were significant changes and upgrades between diamondback and electric not all the features will be in both.